# eclipse vs tomcat deployment - exported war (partially) fails while the project runs in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat, unicode, servlet-3.0

I have a webapp in eclipse juno - when I hit *Run on server* runs fine - either inside eclipse's browser (I am on windows) or in FF.

Right click > **export war** > dump this into $CATALINA_HOME/webapps > all is working fine (got unpacked alright) ***EXCEPT***

- my custom tags - I had a `WEB-INF\functions.tld` file which is apparently not read. The only difference between the auto-generated eclipse `server.xml` (in `Servers` project) and the default Tomcat `server.xml` was the line :

  ```
  <Context docBase="ted2012" path="/ted2012" 
  reloadable="true"source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ted2012"/>
  ```

`source` being a WTP specific attribute.
*This I managed to solve* - see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12956256/281545)

- Tomcat won't get the Url correctly through - see the pics in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12956256/281545).

Questions :

1. (Unsolved) Why Tomcat does not decode the Url correctly - **while eclipse does** ? Where is the failure ? Do see my specific [question for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914983/webapp-behaves-as-expected-when-run-from-eclipse-while-when-exported-as-war-fail) for extensive details on the call stack and where exactly tomcat fails
2. Why did not tomcat see the tld in the first place while eclipse did ? Why did I have to edit the `web.xml` ? (worked around in my answer, should be another question)

The code is in [github](https://github.com/Utumno/ted2012) - in the file INSTRUCTIONS.txt there are detailed instructions to set the project up and reproduce the bug pictured in my answer below.

Tomcat 7.0.32, eclipse 4.2, java 1.7.9

Comment: It's hard to give an answer as your whole URL encoding/decoding library is utterly superfluous if you just 1) set JSP's page encoding to UTF-8, 2) set Tomcat's URI encoding to UTF-8 and 3) use JSTL `<c:url>`/`<c:param>` to construct encoded URLs in JSP whenever applicable (in other words, when you just follow the standard practices as to dealing with UTF-8 data, see further also http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html to understand it better).

Comment: @BalusC I was trying not having to edit the server's xml - it should work - at least it works just I expect it in Eclipse - this one really escapes me. Btw I placed the bounty on this one erroneously : the correct one is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914983/webapp-behaves-as-expected-when-run-from-eclipse-while-when-exported-as-war-fail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For decoding URIs correctly, you need URIEncoding connector attribute in Tomcat:

```
<connector ... URIEncoding="UTF-8" ... />
```

See my rant https://stackoverflow.com/a/15587140/995876

So it doesn't come with normal code, you need it in the application server configuration separately or use an application server that defaults to UTF-8. There is no way to affect this from code unfortunately.

Drop the `decodeRequest` and never use `new String/getBytes` without explicit encoding argument.

---

Alternative.

If you can't edit the server connector configuration, you can fix your code by providing the encoding explicitly to `new String`:

```
public static String decodeRequest(String parameter) {
     return new String(parameter.getBytes("iso-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
}
```

Comment: Thanks - but why it goes through rightly in eclipse and not in exported war in tomcat ? Actually _this is the thing I was trying to debug and I need an answer on this_. Suppose one can't edit the server configuration. See my other question for details on my method : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914983/webapp-behaves-as-expected-when-run-from-eclipse-while-when-exported-as-war-fail. Actually it should work (it does in eclipse anyway) - so where is the failure ? Notice the url is spelled correctly

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D AFAIK, the war just has the application, not the *server* configuration.

Comment: But I do not mess with the server configuration ! That's the point of the way I do it ! The code is in github - maybe give it a whirl ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D this is the line in config where you would place the URIEncoding attribute https://github.com/Utumno/ted2012/blob/GitHub2/conf/Servers_eclipse_project_tomcat7_conf/server.xml#L70

Comment: I know - I have done it this way - I know how to do it this way - I don't understand why the `URLDecoder.decode(new String(parameter.getBytes("iso-8859-1")), CHARSET_FOR_URL_ENCODING);` - behaves fine in Eclipse deploy and not in war deploy - believe me I have not put a bounty to be told I have to change the Connector! I repeat see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914983/webapp-behaves-as-expected-when-run-from-eclipse-while-when-exported-as-war-fail

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D the URIEncoding is for so that you can just do `String name = request.getParameter("name")` without further plumbing. As for your current code, you are using `new String` without encoding parameter, which defaults to platform default encoding, which seems to be different when you launch with eclipse vs tomcat.

Comment: Where is the difference set ? Read the question - I compared the configs. Notice I ask 2 questions btw

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D it's not about the config but the platform default encoding because you are using `new String` without explicit encoding. Try to print `Charset.defaultCharset()` in both environments - it should be different.

Comment: Did try this and tomcat printed windows-1252 while eclipse printed UTF-8 (edited my _answer_) - actually when I go to prefs > workspace > text file encoding and set the default (Cp1252) _**Eclipse also fails**_ - so yeah, an explanation on it (and a workaround preferably) and some info on why do I need to edit the web.xml for tomcat to see the tld and we're there :)

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D There are solutions in my answer, the fixed `decodeRequest` is a work-around while the connector attribute is a real fix that just works without any plubming in code.

Comment: `return URLDecoder.decode(new String(parameter.getBytes("iso-8859-1"),
    CHARSET_FOR_URL_ENCODING), CHARSET_FOR_URL_ENCODING);` did it - add something in your answer for the tld encoding - and if you could recommend me a [s]link[/s], [s]book[/s], clinic for the java charset experience...

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D The urldecoder is superfluous, you can do it with `return new String(parameter.getBytes("iso-8859-1"), CHARSET_FOR_URL_ENCODING);`

Comment: Yes true (despite having first url encoded the parameter (?)) Btw - does `request.getParameter` call `URL.decode()` ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D yes the servlet automatically urldecodes, there is no urldecoding needed to be done by you. Just the ISO > UTF8 conversion.

Comment: I will be asking a question for `parameter.getBytes("iso-8859-1")` - I am trying to locate where in the tomcat source does this requirement for "iso-8859-1" comes from - should I hardcode it like this or is liable to change ? Meanwhile please try a guess for the second question - this bounty is ending soon :)

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D `new String(parameter.getBytes("iso-8859-1"), "UTF-8")` is a backwards hack to overcome the incorrect decoding done by servlet automatically. It wouldn't even be possible if the encoding wasn't ISO-8859-1 because ISO-8859-1 is the only encoding to fully retain the original binary data, with exact byte<->codepoint matches. The servlet will incorrectly decode any query string (but not POST params, see the rant linked in my answer) always as ISO-8859-1. You don't need this at all if you just set `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` in tomcat server.xml configuration connector element.

Comment: " It wouldn't even be possible if the encoding wasn't ISO-8859-1 because ISO-8859-1 is _the only encoding to fully retain the original binary data_, with exact byte<->codepoint matches." Thanks ! - I will be posting a question investigating this further - I want to be able to do this in code. Please add some info on the need for editing the web.xml for tomcat to see the tld in your answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D I don't know much about Tomcat to know that sorry, just encodings :P

Answer (score 1):

One thing that helped was to add to the `web-xml` :

```xml
<jsp-config>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>
            functions
        </taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>
            functions.tld
        </taglib-location>
    </taglib>
</jsp-config>
```

Now tomcat (7.0.30) sees my taglib which is used to encode URIs.

---

Strange thing : when I print the username with system out I get ???? in tomcat's console instead of hieroglyphs. Maybe this points to the issue ? In my controller I have :

```java
final String username = Helpers.decodeRequest(request
                .getParameter("user"));
System.out.println("ProfileController.doGet() user name DECODED : "
                                + username);
```

where :

```java
private static final String CHARSET_FOR_URL_ENCODING = "UTF-8";

public static String decodeRequest(String parameter)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset()); // EDIT: suggested by @Esailija
    if (parameter == null)
        return null;
    System.out.println("decode - request.getBytes(\"iso-8859-1\"):"
            + new String(parameter.getBytes("iso-8859-1")));
    System.out.println("decode - request.getBytes(\"iso-8859-1\") BYTES:"
            + parameter.getBytes("iso-8859-1"));
    for (byte iterable_element : parameter.getBytes("iso-8859-1")) {
        System.out.println(iterable_element);
    }
    System.out.println("decode - request.getBytes(\"UTF-8\"):"
            + new String(parameter.getBytes(CHARSET_FOR_URL_ENCODING))); // UTF-8
    return URLDecoder.decode(new String(parameter.getBytes("iso-8859-1")),
            CHARSET_FOR_URL_ENCODING);
}
```

So tomcat :

```
windows-1252 // EDIT: suggested by @Esailija
decode - request.getBytes("iso-8859-1"):╬╡╬╗╬╗╬╖╬╜╬▒╧?╬▒
decode - request.getBytes("iso-8859-1") BYTES:[B@d171825
-50
-75
-50
-69
-50
-69
-50
-73
-50
-67
-50
-79
-49
-127
-50
-79
decode - request.getBytes("UTF-8"):├Ä┬╡├Ä┬╗├Ä┬╗├Ä┬╖├Ä┬╜├Ä┬▒├?┬?├Ä┬▒
ProfileController.doGet() user name DECODED : ╬╡╬╗╬╗╬╖╬╜╬▒╧?╬▒
???????? // user Dao System.out.println("ελληναρα");
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@67322bd9: SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='╬╡╬╗╬╗╬╖╬╜╬▒╧?╬▒'
ProfileController.doGet() user : null
```

Eclipse :

```
UTF-8 // EDIT: suggested by @Esailija
decode - request.getBytes("iso-8859-1"):ελληναρα
decode - request.getBytes("iso-8859-1") BYTES:[B@44c353ae
-50
-75
-50
-69
-50
-69
-50
-73
-50
-67
-50
-79
-49
-127
-50
-79
decode - request.getBytes("UTF-8"):ÎµÎ»Î»Î·Î½Î±ÏÎ±
ProfileController.doGet() user name DECODED : ελληναρα
ελληναρα // user Dao System.out.println("ελληναρα");
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@73aae7c6: SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='ελληναρα'
ProfileController.doGet() user : com.ted.domain.User@4b22015d
```

EDIT : if I change the eclipse encoding in prefs > workspace > text file encoding and set the default (Cp1252)

```
windows-1252
decode - request.getBytes("iso-8859-1"):Î»Î±Î»Î±ÎºÎ·Ï‚
decode - request.getBytes("iso-8859-1") BYTES:[B@5ef1946a
-50
// same bytes ....
decode - request.getBytes("UTF-8"):ÃŽÂ»ÃŽÂ±ÃŽÂ»ÃŽÂ±ÃŽÂºÃŽÂ·Ã?Â‚
ProfileController.doGet() user name DECODED : Î»Î±Î»Î±ÎºÎ·Ï‚
ÎµÎ»Î»Î·Î½Î±Ï?Î±
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@4646ebd8: SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='Î»Î±Î»Î±ÎºÎ·Ï‚'
ProfileController.doGet() user : null
```

***and Eclipse also fails***

---

**NB :** Tomcat does print the correct url in the address bar

[image]

Eclipse is fine :

[image]

Notice that Firefox automatically decodes the Url (to my bewilderment)