# In JSP, how can I get GET parameters using utf8 encoding?

Tags: jsp, encoding, utf-8

I am using **GlassFish 4**, and my JSP file is simple:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%= request.getParameter("a") %>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my request `GET index.jsp?a=历史`, and the output is:

```
åå²
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: try this <%=request.getParameter("a").getBytes("iso-8859-1"), "UTF-8")%>

Comment: One of my classmates have found it, but is there is more convient way to change the default encoding of URL into utf8?

Comment: check this URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365806/why-the-character-is-corrupted-when-use-request-getparameter-in-java

Answer (score 5):

You can use this code "a_receive = new String(a_receive.getBytes("ISO8859_1"), "UTF-8");"

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <% a_receive = request.getParameter("a") 
           a_receive = new String(a_receive.getBytes("ISO8859_1"), "UTF-8");
%>
        <%=a_receive %>
    </body>
</html>
```