# Convert Hindi Output à¤à¥ à¤µà¤¿à¤¨à¤¿à¤¯à¤®à¤¨ à¤à¤§à¤¿à¤¨à¤¿à¤¯à¤®?

Tags: java

à¤à¥ à¤µà¤¿à¤¨à¤¿à¤¯à¤®à¤¨ à¤à¤§à¤¿à¤¨à¤¿à¤¯à¤®

This output I obtain when I translated an English sentence. Is there any way to make it readable form ??

The Goal is to translate English Sentence to Hindi. The Hindi translated output is correctly obtained in the console. I need to write it to text file.

The translated sentence is set to "translation" and by getParameter() it is tried to save in to the file.

String translation = request.getParameter("translation");
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileDir,true), "UTF-8");
        BufferedWriter fbw = new BufferedWriter(writer);
fbw.write(translation);

[Output file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3dUwvhXVYB2QnBrMHJVMVNjM1E)

[Output file 1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3dUwvhXVYB2dDNCQWZIME50NWc)

Comment: I suspect this is an issue of the coding of your console. But how do you get this output?

Comment: show some code that u tried. From where u got the string à¤à¥ à¤µà¤¿à¤¨à¤¿à¤¯?

Comment: Please show us your code and your input.  Otherwise, we can't help you find the problem.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. This will help people to help you. You might even end up solving it yourself! *:)*. Also see [ask].

Comment: You won't be able to fix that string. You need to fix the method obtaining it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with mismatching character encoding (like UTF-8).
Make sure the character encoding of data that is returned from the request parameter is in UTF-8 encoding.
If the data is in a different encoding, you will have to use that encoding while writing to the file.

Comment: You can try using ISO-8859-1. I guess you are getting the data from an http service. ISO-8859-1 is the default charset for http.

Comment: I checked the character encoding of the data returned by using         String val=request.getCharacterEncoding(); System.out.println(val); and it returns "null".  Also I checked using ISO-8859-1 but no change in the output.

Comment: It obviously won't be ISO-8859-1, as that charset doesn't include the Devanagari characters.  It would have  to be UTF-8 or UTF-16, if this is actually the cause of the problem.

Comment: In which console you are seeing the correct output? How are you printing it?

Comment: In the eclipse's console,  it is printing the output correctly. Simply using System.out.println(); as I have given the  pageEncoding and CharacterEncoding as UTF-8 in the beginning of the tags I think its printing properly.

Comment: If it is working like that, I don't think there is an issue with the file. Can u upload the generated file ? Which editor are you using to view the file?

Comment: Please upload it as a *.txt* file, so that i can verify it's contents.

Comment: Thanks a lot...You asked me to upload the file na..So I thought of how to upload here.Then I thought I will share the link after uploading to google drive. But suddenly I just opened after uploading using "Open with google docs"....To my surprise, I able to view the translated output. Then I choose the libre office 5 and I was able to view the content. As you mentioned earlier this might be a problem with my editor that I am choosing for viewing..... Anyways thanks because, If you don't ask for uploading I may not have viewed this surprise...Thanks again :)

Comment: So we can conclude that there is no issue with the code. And the issue is that your text editor is not supporting Hindi characters.  
Please feel free to upvote or mark the answer as correct is you feel so. :)

Comment: But why I am able to view output file properly and not the output1 file with the same libre office 5??

Comment: I think output1 is having corrupted data. Can you tell me the differences in both the files and the way you generated them?

Comment: Problem solved ....:) There was an error in my code actually...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365806/why-the-character-is-corrupted-when-use-request-getparameter-in-java I referred this link