# Are extended ASCII chars [äöå] allowed in URLs?

Tags: url, slug, extended-ascii

I have seen some websites that use äöå-characters in their slugs (they don't convert them to aoo). So what's the case?

Answer (score 2):

Åå (as in affOrd), Ää (as in Air), and Öö (as in gIrl) are our lovely Swedish additions to the latin alphabet. Nowadays, these can even be used in domain names (at least under the .SE top-level domain). See, for instance, [[http://www.linköping.se](http://www.link%C3%B6ping.se)](http://www.link%C3%B6ping.se). Of course, this is an example of an [IDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name).

Comment: Btw: Markdown really doesn't like IDNs.

Comment: Those were not good examples. 'Å' is more like the 'o' in *afford* [affård]. 'Ä' is like 'ai' in *air* [är]. 'Ö' is like 'i' in *girl* [görl].

Comment: @Gert G: You are probably right! I had a hard time finding good examples!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are!

But see here: [Should I use accented characters in URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386262/should-i-use-accented-characters-in-urls)