# Why is HyperLinkField replacing fields in some URLs and not in others?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a page with a big `GridView` and a `HyperLinkfield` bound to one of the columns, with two parameters, in the following format:

```
 <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="id,nome" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/adm/Clipping/Publicidade/Cadastro/ValorPrograma.aspx?programa={0}&amp;nome={1}" HeaderText="Valores" InsertVisible="False" NavigateUrl="~/adm/Clipping/Publicidade/Cadastro/ValorPrograma.aspx"                 Text="Ajustar valores">
        <ItemStyle ForeColor="#339933" />
 </asp:HyperLinkField>
```

String `DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/adm/Clipping/Publicidade/Cadastro/ValorPrograma.aspx?programa={0}&amp;nome={1}` is replaced by `DataNavigateUrlFields="id,nome"`. **And all is fine**...for some of the rows.  On the other hand, values don't get replaced and the URL is incomplete.

So I went to the database to check if there was some data inconsistency, and pulled data from a field being normally replaced on the `GridView` and for another which isn't being replaced.

[image: Data is consistent in database. Result 1 isn't being replaced at all when formink the hyperlinkfield]

Any ideas?

Comment: How about UrlEncoding the database strings?

Comment: Is there a way to do that inside the grid itself or do I need an event hook?

Comment: But I cannot see any related reason for that behaviour.

Comment: I think you need to do that in the RowDataBound event. As for the reason why do it, my guess is, ç and/or õ are invalid characters for an URL and cause the entire string to be left out. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386262/should-i-use-accented-characters-in-urls

Comment: @Hanno the funny thing is that, from the database picture I showed, record #1 is the problematic one and the record with ç and õ works **fine**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with [Hanno's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/964955/hanno) statement [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069315/why-is-hyperlinkfield-replacing-fields-in-some-urls-and-not-in-others#comment21190849_15069315), this is likely due to invlaid URL characters.

This is one way you could encode the characters from the RowDataBound event:

```
protected void yourGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        i = 0; // the ordinal of the column you need to encode

        DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
        string id = Server.UrlEncode(rowView["id"].ToString());
        string nome = Server.UrlEncode(rowView["nome"].ToString());

        string newURL = String.Format("~/adm/Clipping/Publicidade/Cadastro/ValorPrograma.aspx?programa={0}&amp;nome={1}", id, nome);

        e.Row.Cells[i].Text = newURL;
    }
}
```

You'll need to have something like this in the markup for your `GridView`, in order to hook it up to the event handler:

```
OnRowDataBound="yourGridView_RowDataBound"
```

Comment: I posted my answer in C#, because I don't see that you specified a language.  If you're using VB.NET, the response is similar, but let me know if you need help translating it.

Comment: I'm using C#, but your answer didn't work for me. It gives me an "Object reference not set" on the `Server.UrlEncode(rowView["id"].ToString());`, probably because the rowView object is null (can't debug because it's a production system here). Just note that I've made the necessary changes for it to work  but may have missed something.

Comment: Found the problem, which was indeed an encoding problem (specifically, the `:` char on the URL. My approach was different, though. I preferred to use the HyperlinkField as a TemplateField an make up the URL on the aspx page, as @jadarnel27's example did not work for me. I'll accept your answer because it hits the spot, but the solution needs improvement.

Comment: @marquito Good catch, Anytime you do processing in the RowDataBound event on things like this, you have to make sure you're working with a DataRow (and not a header or footer). I left out the check for that, which is why you were getting null. The updated code should work, although it sounds like your solution is more elegant than this.

Comment: I wouldn't say "elegant", as mixing presentation and code processing has never been a favourite of mine. You believe I should also answer the question?

Comment: @marquito Ah, that's a good point.  It certainly takes less code than this, though, which sometimes is a plus =)  Feel free to add your solution as another answers, there are no rules against that here.  Out of curiosity, did my updated code work without errors?

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by [Hanno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/964955/hanno)'s [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069315/why-is-hyperlinkfield-replacing-fields-in-some-urls-and-not-in-others#comment21190849_15069315) and replied by [jadarnel27](https://stackoverflow.com/users/861565/jadarnel27)'s actual [Reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15071181/461076), the problem is related to URL character encoding (specifically in this case the encoding of the `:` character).

To solve this issue, I suggest using a `TemplateField` instead of the `HyperLink` field, as follows

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Valores" InsertVisible="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
                    NavigateUrl='<%# "~/adm/Clipping/Publicidade/Cadastro/ValorPrograma.aspx?programa=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("id").ToString()) + "&nome=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("nome").ToString()) %>'
                    Text="Ajustar valores"></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle ForeColor="#339933" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

The key concept is using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` in the template itself instead of calling the `RowDataBound` event.

With that done, the database data will be properly encoded before making up the URL and it just works.

Comment: I agree that this is a cleaner way of solving the problem. I'll keep this one in mind!