# Use ÅÄÖ in .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I need help with my .htaccess file.

The links are: http://example.com/se-stockholm.html

But when I select a city that contains ÅÄÖ will the url become:

http://example.com/se-rebro.html and not se-örebro.html

My .htacess file looks like this today:

```
RewriteRule ^ ([^ / \.] +) - ([^ / \.] +). Html? $ Search.php? Co = $ 1 & location = $ 2
```

How can I add so it prints with ÅÄÖ?

Comment: Where exactly does the URL become `se-rebro.html`? Is this in the (HTML) output of some other page? Or does it get changed by a redirect or something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I use accented characters in URLs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386262/should-i-use-accented-characters-in-urls)

Comment: This needs clarification to be answerable.

Answer (score 1):

Add to you *.htaccess* or in *httpd.conf* the following configuration line (directive):

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

[Apache HTTP Server Manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#adddefaultcharset):

> This directive specifies a default value for the media type charset
>   parameter (the name of a character encoding) to be added to a response
>   if and only if the response's content-type is either text/plain or
>   text/html. This should override any charset specified in the body of
>   the response via a META element, though the exact behavior is often
>   dependent on the user's client configuration. A setting of
>   AddDefaultCharset Off disables this functionality. AddDefaultCharset
>   On enables a default charset of iso-8859-1. Any other value is assumed
>   to be the charset to be used, which should be one of the IANA
>   registered charset values for use in MIME media types.

Don't dorget to restart your *httpd* server in case of editing *httpd.conf*.

#### EDIT 1:

Looking at your *rewriterules*, I would recommend you trying the following insted:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)/(.*).html?$ search.php?co=$1&location=$2&keyword=$3 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*).html?$ search.php?co=$1&keyword=$2 
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*).html?$ search.php?co=$1&location=$2
```

Comment: Thans for your answer. I add AddDefaultCharset utf-8 in my .htaccess and in httpd.conf, but it is the same problem :/

Comment: Please make sure that there is only one `AddDefaultCharset` directive!

Comment: @Paoh Does your `RewriteRule` works with other requests, that doesn't contain special characters?

Comment: @Paoh What is the output of `curl -I yourdomain.com` when running it on command prompt?

Comment: @Rostovtsev It's works with out a problem, only problem is ÅÅÖ. This is the full .htacess

`AddDefaultCharset utf-8`
`RewriteEngine on`

`RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)-([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+).html?$ search.php?co=$1&location=$2&keyword=$3`
`RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+).html?$ search.php?co=$1&keyword=$2`
`RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)-([^/\.]+).html?$ search.php?co=$1&location=$2`

`ErrorDocument 404 /404.php`

Comment: what did you mean with curl -I yourdomain.com, hehe :o)

Comment: Can you run from SSH `curl -I yourdomain.com`?

Comment: @Paoh Try updated *rewriterules* and let me know if it works for you!?

Comment: This is unlikely to  work because UTF-8 characters have no business being in a URL. They will probably be URL encoded. See [Unicode characters in URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2742852)

Comment: @Pekka웃 Then what would be the solution? Congratulations on `7,000` answers - Amazing!! :)

Comment: Thanks, had't noticed! :) I don't understand the OP's question well enough  to understand what goes wrong in the first place. @Paoh you didn't answer Jonathan's question in the comment above. Where exactly are things going wrong?