# give an example of using cyirillic in regex java

Tags: java, regex, string

How to make regex of a `cyrillic` string, i want to use it in this a way somehow:

`String.replaceAll("Кириллица","")`

Of course it doesn't work. What am I to do, to make it work?

Ok,I see that the method works, but it doesn't work for me. How can I check, why does method not execute?

...

Hm, I tried to use `s1 = s1.replaceAll("[\\p{InCyrillic}]", "");` for the string I get through the sockets. it works great, all cyrillic chars disapperar, including the word `"Экзамен"`, but if I try  `s1=s1.replaceAll("Экзамен","")` nothing happens.

But method `s1=s1.replaceAll("Экзамен","")` worked in the same program for a static string defined in this program. I guess that problem may be because of wrong charset, but I still can't understand what am I doing wrong. The charset of the string is `windows-1251`. I tried to experiment with charset in program (it is jsp now), using methods

```
System.setProperty("file.encoding", "windows-1251");
response.setCharacterEncoding("windows-1251");
```

tried converting the string from one charset to another. And nothing changes

Comment: What does not work? Can you give an example? There should be no problems.

Comment: here is an example: I have a string c with cyrillic, that has Экзамен sequence of chars. I do
c=c.replaceAll("Экзамен","");
and get a string c=Введение в специальность (Б.3.2.1-ПиКО)60,3Экзамен

Comment: no, the problem is not about tomcat or charset. Can it be so that problem is that i'm doing replace in a long string?

Comment: It should work. If the file is not correctly compiled with correct encoding, or the text input's encoding is incorrect, the replacement will fail.

Comment: Do you want to replace the sequence "Экзамен", or replace every character in "Экзамен"?

Comment: the sequense. ok, it maybe that the encoding is incorrect. i'll try out

Answer (score 5):

It might be more clear if you show your result in case @Henry's answer.
I suppose that the issue in characters or encoding.
To identify is the String in cyrillic you can with this code:

```
String s1 = "Экзaмен";
s1 = s1.replaceAll("[\\p{InCyrillic}]", "");
System.out.println(s1);
```

The code will remove all cyrillic characters and you can identify invalid encoded characters.

If your result will be like "a" or "e", or "ae", It means that in your string exist latin characters which simular to cyrillic, so you should replace using this regex

```
 s1 = s1.replaceAll("Экз[aa]м[ee]н", "");
```

where [a-is cyrillic character and a-is latin character] and so on.

If your result will be as "Экзaмен", the issue in encoding and I hope this link will help you

[How to determine if a String contains invalid encoded characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887148/how-to-determine-if-a-string-contains-invalid-encoded-characters)

Answer (score 1):

Just tried this:

```
String s1 = "Введение в специальность (Б.3.2.1-ПиКО)60,3Экзамен";
String s2 = s1.replaceAll("Экзамен", "");
System.out.println(s2);
```

The output is:

```
Введение в специальность (Б.3.2.1-ПиКО)60,3
```

Comment: hm, but why then I get another result... Maybe problems with charset, or Tomcat...
Strange thing is that method doesnt work only on cyrillic. But I don't see the problem.