# Struts2 - pass enye character from jsp to struts 2 action class properly

Tags: java, mysql, struts2, tomcat7, jquery-ajaxq

I have a webapp built using Struts2, with Tomcat 7 as application server and MySQL database as backend. Now i pass some string from my jsp file using jquery ajax but this string contains special characters (ñ - enye). When i alert it before passing to the class via jquery ajax, it displays fine but when i receive it in the java class, it displays like Ã± . I need the string to be as exact as possible as i am querying the mysql database with an entry similar to the string.

All jsp pages have `<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>` and `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>` in head as well as the jquery contentType `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`.

What could be the possible solution to this? Thanks for your reply. Here are the screenshots by the way. Thanks for your help :)

[image: alert from jsp]
[image: system.out.println on console]
[image: the database entry that needs to be matched]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily found the answer within StackOverflow. Thanks guys, you're the best :)

[How to determine if a String contains invalid encoded characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887148/how-to-determine-if-a-string-contains-invalid-encoded-characters)